# injective dimension of dualizing complex

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, derived-categories

Let $R$ be a balanced dualizing complex of a Noetherian connected graded algebras $A$. Dose one always have $\text{id}_A R = \text{id}_{A^{op}} R$?

Thanks a lot.